# VBA suddenly decides it needs declarations

Tags: vba

I've been using a few macros I wrote for a few days now without issue. Upon restarting my computer, whenever I go to use a macro with a variable that hasn't been declared, an error message pops up. Its a fairly easy workaround to do

```
Dim variablename as Variant
```

everywhere its an issue, as I'm assuming that this is what was done implicitly, but is there a reason vba would have not cared in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have the line `Option Explicit` written at the start of your module.

This [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (recommanded) forces explicit declaration of all variables in a file.

Comment: Ha! I just copied a small function that had that as a first line... initially wondered what it did but forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: It's good practice to turn it on, it means you don't have a shedload of `Variants` lurking about. You should also declare things properly, again, just for good practice and error avoidance.

Comment: @SkipIntro, I totally agree

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can check Require Variable Declaration checkbox which will add `Otion Explicit` for you.
Its available under Tools > Options