# Variable not found in simple loop

Tags: vba, loops

Getting a compile error "Variable not found" and it is highlighting the C.  This is a simple code and am not sure why I am getting this error.  The range is defined on the static tab and everything looks fine.  Please help!

```
Sub RunPull()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Sheets("STATIC").Select

For Each C In Worksheets("STATIC").Range("RunRange").Cells
    Calculate
    Sheets("STATIC").Range("RunTag") = C
    RunSeperateMacro
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False
```

End Sub

Comment: try adding a new line `Dim C as Variant` after the first line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA suddenly decides it needs declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592000/vba-suddenly-decides-it-needs-declarations)

Answer (score 0):

You have failed to initialize the variable called **C** in your code.  This will work properly:

```
Sub RunPull()
Dim C as Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Sheets("STATIC").Select

For Each C In Worksheets("STATIC").Range("RunRange").Cells
    Calculate
    Sheets("STATIC").Range("RunTag") = C
    RunSeperateMacro
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Alternately, you can see if this statement occurs at the top of your module and remove it:

```
Option Explicit
```

This line of code forces you to explicitly declare all of your variables.